# Framework Slim com Apache2.4

Tags: php, ajax, apache, slim, routing

Bom dia.
Estou criando uma API para disponibilizar um serviço para outras aplicações.
Tenho o seguinte cenário.
Um sistema para disponibilizar o serviço. Este sistema tem um virtualhost configurado.
A uri é http://meuservico.com.br/lib/api/api.php.
Ao acessar essa url, internamente usando get - o caso que já testei pelo menos - ele imprime a mensagem na tela.

```
$this->app->get("/", function () {
        $header = get_headers('http://www.meuservico.com.br', 1);
        $receive = $header['Content-Type'][0];
        $arr_receive = split(";", $receive);
        echo $arr_receive[0];
    });
```

Criei um projeto externo e este rola no localhost também, porém não tem um virtualhost definido.
Segue ´código para acesso externo.

```
        $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: 'http://meuservico.com.br/lib/api/api.php',
            data: { name: 'norm' },
            // dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (request) {
                console.log(request);
            }
        });        
    });
```

Nesse caso, recebo o seguinte erro.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://meuservico.com.br/lib/api/api.php?name=norm. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.e-sms.com.br' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é um problema com Apache e nem com o Slim, faltam headers, se tem acesso ao arquivo `http://meuservico.com.br/lib/api/api.php` você editar ele adicionar os headers, pela mensagem de erro ele já tem, mas só libera pro `http://www.e-sms.com.br`, então troque:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.e-sms.com.br
```

Por

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Todavia se não tiver acesso ao arquivo api.php, então pode usar o proprio jQuery aplicando `crossDomain: true,` assim:

```
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'http://meuservico.com.br/lib/api/api.php',
        data: { name: 'norm' },
        // dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (request) {
            console.log(request);
        }
    });
```

Note que isso não é "ajax de verdade", mas funciona bem semelhante.